# Global filters for different data sources (with common tables)

Tags: filter, filtering, datasource, tableau-api

I am currently working on Tableau using 2 data sources using each a join of 2 tables (named A, B, C):

- Data source 1: A-B
- Data source 2: A-C

Basically, A contains the major information that I need and then I join data from B and C to get the extra information I need for each report I am doing.

I then do a dashboard that contains reports using the data source 1 and 2.

My problem now is that I am filtering this dashboard using a dimension in A and I would like it to apply to all worksheets (e.g. for those using data sources 1 and those using data source 2).

I thought that because A is the common table in all data sources, that using a dimension in A would be ok to filter everything but it seems that it is not the case.

Is there a way to fix this?

I read some forums about creating a parameter. However, the filtering I am doing is basically as follows: I want my users to choose 1 shop name. They can find it either by:

1. Typing the name in the 'Shop name' quick filter,
2. Using a combination of the quick filters 'Region' and 'country' to then get a drop down of 'Shop Name' that has a reduced amounts of shop names (easier when the user knows where the shop is but does not remember its exact name).

Using a parameter would not allow me to do this anymore since all of this is based on 'filtering the relevant values'.

Does anyone have any recommendations?

Comment: Curious as to why you created two data sources. Could you do only one since both use table A? Otherwise, you might be able to do data blending. http://kb.tableau.com/articles/knowledgebase/join-vs-relationship

Comment: Like @Bernardo said, you may need to reconsider why you use two different data sources. Or you can wait for Tableau 10 to come out later this year, which has a cross data source filter feature that will take care of your problem.

Comment: Hi both,
I am new to Tableau so it is possible that I am not tackling this right.
Table A has for example basic information about shops.
Table B has the number of visits done for each shops (multiple lines per shop)
Table C has the number of sales per shop (multiple lines per shop)

Each table has a column with a shop Id. Originally I wanted to do left joins between A and B and then another left join with C. But there is too much data. So I split it.

Comment: I want to second @SamM. You should either wait for cross datasource filters in version 10, or use a common datasource for each of the visualizations.